# AWS SageMaker fails loading PyTorch .pth weights

Tags: pytorch, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

I want to deploy PyTorch model to AWS SageMaker endpoint and experience some issues. Below there is a code and logs. Basically, I have .pth file for model trained outside SageMaker (Azure) and I want to move it to AWS. `macro_model.tar.gz` contains model weights `macro_model.pth` file and inference code with `requirements.txt`.

**Expected behavior**

Model deployed to endpoint and generates predictions

**Issue**

SageMaker `model_fn` function doesn't see model weights.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Deployment code in SageMaker Notebook:

```
import boto3
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorchModel
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import json
import numpy as np

role = get_execution_role()
conn = boto3.client('s3')

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='s3://.../macro_model.tar.gz',
                             framework_version="1.7", py_version="py3",
                             role=role, entry_point='inference.py', source_dir='code')

predictor = pytorch_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge', endpoint_name='...')
```

`macro_model.tar.gz` structure:

```
|   macro_model
|           |--macro_model.pth
|
|           code
|               |--inference.py
|               |--requirements.txt
|
```

`model_fn` function implementation:

```
def model_fn(model_dir):
    logging.info('Loading the model...')

    layers = [
        nn.Linear(512, 512),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Dropout(0.3),
        nn.Linear(512, 2)
      ]
    
    logging.info('Layers initiated...')
    model = VideoRecog_Model1(layers,7)
    logging.info('Model initiated...')
    with open(os.path.join(model_dir, 'macro_model.pth'), 'rb') as f:
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(f))
    
    
    model.to(device).eval()
    logging.info('Done loading model')
    return model
```

Logs:

```
2021-06-27T12:24:56.241+02:00   Collecting opencv-python-headless Downloading opencv_python_headless-4.5.2.54-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (38.2 MB)

2021-06-27T12:24:57.242+02:00   Collecting moviepy==1.0.3 Downloading moviepy-1.0.3.tar.gz (388 kB)
    2021-06-27T12:24:57.242+02:00   Collecting av==8.0.3 Downloading av-8.0.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (37.2 MB)

2021-06-27T12:24:58.243+02:00   Collecting decorator<5.0,>=4.0.2 Downloading decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)

2021-06-27T12:24:58.243+02:00   Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0,>=4.11.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from moviepy==1.0.3->-r /opt/ml/model/code/requirements.txt (line 2)) (4.59.0)

2021-06-27T12:24:58.243+02:00   Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=2.8.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from moviepy==1.0.3->-r /opt/ml/model/code/requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.22.0)

2021-06-27T12:24:58.243+02:00   Collecting proglog<=1.0.0 Downloading proglog-0.1.9.tar.gz (10 kB)
    
2021-06-27T12:24:59.244+02:00   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from moviepy==1.0.3->-r /opt/ml/model/code/requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.19.1)
    
2021-06-27T12:24:59.244+02:00   Collecting imageio<3.0,>=2.5 Downloading imageio-2.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)
    
2021-06-27T12:24:59.244+02:00   Collecting imageio_ffmpeg>=0.2.0 Downloading imageio_ffmpeg-0.4.4-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (26.9 MB)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:00.244+02:00   Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from imageio<3.0,>=2.5->moviepy==1.0.3->-r /opt/ml/model/code/requirements.txt (line 2)) (8.2.0)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:00.244+02:00   Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.8.1->moviepy==1.0.3->-r /opt/ml/model/code/requirements.txt (line 2)) (2020.12.5)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:00.244+02:00   Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.8.1->moviepy==1.0.3->-r /opt/ml/model/code/requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.8)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:00.244+02:00   Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.8.1->moviepy==1.0.3->-r /opt/ml/model/code/requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.25.11)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:00.244+02:00   Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.8.1->moviepy==1.0.3->-r /opt/ml/model/code/requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.4)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:00.244+02:00   Building wheels for collected packages: moviepy, proglog Building wheel for moviepy (setup.py): started Building wheel for moviepy (setup.py): finished with status 'done' Created wheel for moviepy: filename=moviepy-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl size=110726 sha256=d90e44b117edbb3d061d7d3d800e6e687392ac6b06f9001f82559c4dd88f19c4 Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/be/dc/17/8b4d5a63bcd05dc44db7da57e193372ccd333617293f9deebe Building wheel for proglog (setup.py): started
    
2021-06-27T12:25:01.245+02:00   Building wheel for proglog (setup.py): finished with status 'done' Created wheel for proglog: filename=proglog-0.1.9-py3-none-any.whl size=6147 sha256=da1b510090c3b87cf4c564558a64b996bc1fdf34d6d15fd56c14c9c776f5b366 Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e7/11/a0/7e65f734d33043735a557b1244569cca327353db9068158076
    
2021-06-27T12:25:01.245+02:00   Successfully built moviepy proglog
    
2021-06-27T12:25:01.245+02:00   Installing collected packages: proglog, imageio-ffmpeg, imageio, decorator, opencv-python-headless, moviepy, av
    
2021-06-27T12:25:02.246+02:00   Attempting uninstall: decorator Found existing installation: decorator 5.0.9 Uninstalling decorator-5.0.9:
    
2021-06-27T12:25:03.246+02:00   Successfully uninstalled decorator-5.0.9
    
2021-06-27T12:25:05.252+02:00   Successfully installed av-8.0.3 decorator-4.4.2 imageio-2.9.0 imageio-ffmpeg-0.4.4 moviepy-1.0.3 opencv-python-headless-4.5.2.54 proglog-0.1.9
    
2021-06-27T12:25:05.252+02:00   WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.256+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:06,537 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer -
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.256+02:00   Torchserve version: 0.3.1
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.256+02:00   TS Home: /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.256+02:00   Current directory: /

2021-06-27T12:25:07.256+02:00   Temp directory: /home/model-server/tmp
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Number of GPUs: 1
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Number of CPUs: 1
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Max heap size: 14097 M
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Python executable: /opt/conda/bin/python3.6
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Config file: /etc/sagemaker-ts.properties
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Inference address: http://0.0.0.0:8080
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Management address: http://0.0.0.0:8080
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Metrics address: http://127.0.0.1:8082
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Model Store: /.sagemaker/ts/models
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Initial Models: model.mar
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Log dir: /logs
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Metrics dir: /logs
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Netty threads: 0
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Netty client threads: 0
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Default workers per model: 1

2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Blacklist Regex: N/A
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.257+02:00   Maximum Response Size: 6553500
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.258+02:00   Maximum Request Size: 6553500
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.258+02:00   Prefer direct buffer: false
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.258+02:00   Allowed Urls: [file://.*|http(s)?://.*]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.258+02:00   Custom python dependency for model allowed: false
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.258+02:00   Metrics report format: prometheus
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.258+02:00   Enable metrics API: true
    
2021-06-27T12:25:07.258+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:06,597 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Loading initial models: model.mar
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,725 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.archive.ModelArchive - eTag a6e950a7055442d88ff2f182fdef1da3
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,744 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.wlm.ModelManager - Model model loaded.
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,782 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Initialize Inference server with: EpollServerSocketChannel.
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,935 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Inference API bind to: http://0.0.0.0:8080
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,935 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Initialize Metrics server with: EpollServerSocketChannel.
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,937 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Metrics API bind to: http://127.0.0.1:8082
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,996 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Listening on port: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,999 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - [PID]59
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,999 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Torch worker started.
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:08,999 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Python runtime: 3.6.13
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,013 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Connecting to: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000
    
2021-06-27T12:25:09.259+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,039 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Connection accepted: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000.
    
2021-06-27T12:25:10.260+02:00   Model server started.
    
2021-06-27T12:25:10.260+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,768 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-1 TS_METRICS - CPUUtilization.Percent:100.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:model.aws.local,timestamp:1624789509
    
2021-06-27T12:25:10.260+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,776 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskAvailable.Gigabytes:11.663764953613281|#Level:Host|#hostname:model.aws.local,timestamp:1624789509
    
2021-06-27T12:25:10.260+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,777 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskUsage.Gigabytes:12.690078735351562|#Level:Host|#hostname:model.aws.local,timestamp:1624789509
    
2021-06-27T12:25:10.260+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,777 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskUtilization.Percent:52.1|#Level:Host|#hostname:model.aws.local,timestamp:1624789509
    
2021-06-27T12:25:10.260+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,778 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryAvailable.Megabytes:59581.45703125|#Level:Host|#hostname:model.aws.local,timestamp:1624789509
    
2021-06-27T12:25:10.260+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,787 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryUsed.Megabytes:1238.21875|#Level:Host|#hostname:model.aws.local,timestamp:1624789509
    
2021-06-27T12:25:10.260+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:09,788 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryUtilization.Percent:3.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:model.aws.local,timestamp:1624789509
    
2021-06-27T12:25:12.261+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:11,779 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Generating new fontManager, this may take some time...
    
2021-06-27T12:25:13.262+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:12,875 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Loading the model...
    
2021-06-27T12:25:13.262+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:12,906 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Layers initiated...
    
2021-06-27T12:25:14.262+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:13,871 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/r3d_18-b3b3357e.pth" to /root/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoints/r3d_18-b3b3357e.pth
    
2021-06-27T12:25:14.262+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:13,872 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -
    
2021-06-27T12:25:14.262+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:13,972 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 0%| | 0.00/127M [00:00<?, ?B/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:14.262+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,072 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 6%|▌ | 7.30M/127M [00:00<00:01, 76.5MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:14.262+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,172 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 16%|█▋ | 20.7M/127M [00:00<00:00, 114MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,272 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 27%|██▋ | 34.0M/127M [00:00<00:00, 126MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,372 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 38%|███▊ | 48.1M/127M [00:00<00:00, 134MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,472 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 49%|████▉ | 62.1M/127M [00:00<00:00, 139MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,572 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 60%|██████ | 76.8M/127M [00:00<00:00, 144MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,692 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 72%|███████▏ | 91.9M/127M [00:00<00:00, 149MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,794 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 83%|████████▎ | 106M/127M [00:00<00:00, 140MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,852 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 94%|█████████▍| 120M/127M [00:00<00:00, 139MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,987 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Model initiated...
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,988 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Backend worker process died.
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,988 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Backend worker process died.
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,988 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Traceback (most recent call last):
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,988 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 182, in <module>
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,988 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 182, in <module>
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - worker.run_server()
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 154, in run_server
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 154, in run_server
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - self.handle_connection(cl_socket)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 116, in handle_connection
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 116, in handle_connection
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     service, result, code = self.load_model(msg)
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - service, result, code = self.load_model(msg)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 89, in load_model
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,989 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 89, in load_model
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,990 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     service = model_loader.load(model_name, model_dir, handler, gpu, batch_size, envelope)
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,990 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - service = model_loader.load(model_name, model_dir, handler, gpu, batch_size, envelope)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,990 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ts/model_loader.py", line 104, in load
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,990 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - initialize_fn(service.context)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.263+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,990 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/home/model-server/tmp/models/a6e950a7055442d88ff2f182fdef1da3/handler_service.py", line 51, in initialize
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,991 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - super().initialize(context)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,991 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_inference/default_handler_service.py", line 66, in initialize
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,991 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - self._service.validate_and_initialize(model_dir=model_dir)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,991 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_inference/transformer.py", line 158, in validate_and_initialize
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,991 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - self._model = self._model_fn(model_dir)
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,991 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 105, in model_fn
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,991 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 105, in model_fn
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00

2021-06-27 10:25:14,992 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     with open(os.path.join(model_dir, 'macro_model.pth'), 'rb') as f:
    
2021-06-27 10:25:14,992 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - with open(os.path.join(model_dir, 'macro_model.pth'), 'rb') as f:
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00

**2021-06-27 10:25:14,992 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/model-server/tmp/models/a6e950a7055442d88ff2f182fdef1da3/macro_model.pth'**
    
**2021-06-27 10:25:14,992 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/model-server/tmp/models/a6e950a7055442d88ff2f182fdef1da3/macro_model.pth'**
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,994 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - 100%|██████████| 127M/127M [00:00<00:00, 136MB/s]
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,998 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-5-1 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - 9000 Worker disconnected. WORKER_STARTED
    
2021-06-27T12:25:15.264+02:00   2021-06-27 10:25:14,999 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.BatchAggregator - Load model failed: model, error: Worker died.
```

Comment: need to check this method `PyTorchModel`

Answer (score 0):

That is strange, but for unknown reason SageMaker created a folder on the upper level of model weights. Having catalog structure as above described in my question I received a structure which additional folder, so I needed to edit my code as below:

```
model_path =  os.path.join(model_dir, 'macro_model')
with open(os.path.join(model_path , 'macro_model.pth'), 'rb') as f:
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(f))
```

This is confusing, considering the fact, that recently I was able to deploy PyTorch model in the same way as described in the question and there was no folder created.

Hope it will help somebody in future.

Answer (score 0):

I used same directory structure like yours and confronted with similar problem (`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`)

Changing the directory structure (not using parent directory, `macro_model` here) works for me.

Sagemaker docs: [Model directory structure](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#model-directory-structure)

Comment: Loading model weights with path like `model_dir/macro_model` in `model_fn` caused another problem (`NotImplementedError: Please provide a model_fn implementation`) for me, so changing the directory structure is easier imo.